# asp.net - Is my path virtual?

Tags: asp.net, virtual-path

Is there a built-in asp.net method for checking the "virtualness" of a path?

The only way I've been able to do it so far is with the following try block:

```
public void Foo(String path){

    try
    {
        path = Server.MapPath(path);
    }
    catch(HttpException){}

    // do stuff with path
}
```

Comment: In what scope are you talking about "virtual"? There are virtual folders in IIS, and there is the concept of a virtual path in ASP.NET. The two are not necessarily the same.

Comment: I mean a virtual path in asp.net.  Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would the [Path.IsPathRooted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.ispathrooted.aspx) method work?

You're resulting code would be:

```
public void Foo(String path)
{
    if(!Path.IsPathRooted(path))
    {
        path = Server.MapPath(path);
    }

    // do stuff with path
}
```

Comment: Woohoo!  That works like a charm.  I wish the terminology was a bit more consistent though.  Is a non-rooted path the same as a virtual path?

Comment: Like you said, this is mostly a problem of terminology.  You are using "virtual" but a more correct term would be "relative".    Any path that doesn't have an absolute path (ie C:\Folder\file.txt) would therefore have to be relative to the current directory.

Answer (score 3):

Here is everything you need to know about ASP.Net paths: [Rick Strahl's post "Making Sense of ASP.Net Pahts"](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Dec/21/Making-Sense-of-ASPNET-Paths)

Comment: +1 for Strahl - a genius who I rarely understand.  Great link by the way, really helped me out.