# ASP.NET: IsVirtualPath?

Tags: asp.net, virtual-path

Is there a function to determine whether a URI is a valid virtual path? I'm given a string and need to use Server.MapPath() on it without throwing an Exception when the string is not a valid virtual path.

**Vote to close my question. Answer is @ [asp.net - Is my path virtual?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308723/asp-net-is-my-path-virtual).**

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `File.Exists() and Directory.Exists()` methods to check the output of `Server.MapPath()` and verify that a file/directory exists at the specified path.

```
Dim myPath as String = Server.MapPath('/some/path.aspx')
If File.Exists(myPath) Then
    //Do Something
Else
   If Directory.Exists(myPath) Then
       //Do Something
   Else
       //Invalid path
   End If
End If
```

Comment: If "/some/path.aspx" is a full URL, Server.MapPath() will throw an HttpException.

Comment: True, you can add exception handling for that case. In my experience, when using Server.MapPath, it has been on SERVER variables such as SCRIPT_NAME, which would not give you a full URL. In any case, glad you found your answer :)